# network_selection_disabled_by_wrong_password

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot

I run a debug because my phone did not wan't to connect to Hotspot 2.0 Wi-Fi network. I found it gives the following reason: network_selection_disabled_by_wrong_password.

What are possible reasons? User's credential are valid.